# Optimal time control for the system of two non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system, optimal-control

I have the following system of two non-linear ODE with one control variable (modified model of Lotka-Volterra):

[image: system of two ode]

Here is $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ - some constants, $u$ - control variable.

Also I have initial conditions:
$$
y(0) = y_0,
x(0) = x_0
$$
and the final conditions:
$$
y(t^*) = y^*, x(t^*) =0
$$
Another variant of the final conditions is:
$$
y(t^*) = 0, x(t^*) = x^*
$$
So, I want to find some function $u$, that minimize $t^*$.

Is it possible for this system and how I can do it?